# How to do Fairy Chess problem in O(N^3)?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, dynamic-programming

https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4f1c88e0dec8a

> Fairy Chess (35 Points)
>
> You have a $N \times N$ chess board. An $S$-leaper is a chess piece which can move from square $(x_1,y_1)$ on the board to any other square $(x_2,y_2)$ if $|x_1 - x_2| + |y_1 - y_2| \le S$. The chess board may also contain some pawns. The leaper cannot land on the same square as a pawn. In how many ways can a leaper move $M$ times on the board?
>
> Input:
>   The first line contains the number of test cases $T$. $T$ cases follow. Each case contains integers $N$, $M$ and $S$ on the first line. The next $N$ lines contains $N$ characters each. The $i$th character on the $j$th line is a `.` if the corresponding chess square is empty, `P` if there is a pawn, or `L` if the leaper is situated on that square.
>
> Output:
>   For each case, output the number of ways the leaper can make $M$ moves. Output each answer modulo 1000000007.
>
> Constraints:
>   $$\begin{gather}
> 1 \le T \le 10 \\
> 1 \le S \le N \le 200 \\
> 1 \le M \le 200 \\
> \end{gather}$$
>   There will be exactly one `L` character on the board.
>
> Sample Input:
>
> ```
> 3
> 4 1 1
> ....
> .L..
> .P..
> ....
> 3 2 1
> ...
> ...
> ..L
> 4 3 2
> ....
> ...L
> ..P.
> P...
> ```
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ```
> 4
> 11
> 385
> ```

I wrote a DP solution but with O(N^5).

> Psuedocode for ways function:

```
Memoize[Xmax][Ymax][Nmax];

ways(int X, int Y, int M) // (X,Y) current co-ordinates and M is number of moves to make
{
    if(Memoize[X][Y][M] != -1) // != -1 means we already have the result
        return Memoize[X][Y][M];
    sum=0;
    for all (u,v) such that |X-u| + |Y-v| <= S
        sum += ways(u, v, M-1);

    Memoize[X][Y][M] = sum;
    return sum;

}
```

> Code:

```
/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long ways(long ***DP, char **Chess, int X, int Y, int S, int N, int M);

int main()
{
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while(T>0)
    {
        int N, M, S;
        scanf("%d", &N);
        scanf("%d", &M);
    scanf("%d", &S);
        long ***DP = (long ***) malloc(sizeof(long **) * N);
        int i,j,k;
        char **Chess = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) *N);
        int Xstart;
        int Ystart; //printf("N=%dM=%dS=%d\n", N, M, S);
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
        Chess[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) *N);
        DP[i] = (long **)malloc(sizeof(long *) * N);
            for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            {   //printf("i=%dj=%d\n", i, j);
        DP[i][j] = (long *)malloc(sizeof(long) *(M+1));
                char a;
                scanf(" %c", &a);
                if(a=='L')
                {
                    Xstart = i;
                    Ystart = j;
                }
                Chess[i][j] = a;
        //printf("jf=%d\n", j);
        }
        }

        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            {
                for(k=1;k<M+1;k++)
                {
                    DP[i][j][k] = -1;
                }
                DP[i][j][0] = 1;
            }
        }

       printf("%ld\n", ways(DP, Chess, Xstart, Ystart, S, N, M));
       T--;
    }
}

long ways(long ***DP, char **Chess, int X, int Y, int s, int N, int M)
{
    if(DP[X][Y][M] !=-1)
    {
    //printf("X=%d Y=%d M=%d Val=%ld\n", X, Y, M, DP[X][Y][M]);
    return DP[X][Y][M];
    }
    else
    {
        long sum1 = 0;


        int S,k;
    sum1 += ways(DP, Chess, X, Y, s, N, M-1);

        for(S=1;S<=s;S++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<=S;k++)
            {
                if(k!=0 && (S-k)!=0)
                {
                    if(X+k<N && Y+(S-k) <N && Chess[X+k][Y+(S-k)] != 'P')
                    {
                        Chess[X+k][Y+(S-k)] = 'L';
                        Chess[X][Y] = '.';
                        sum1 += ways(DP, Chess, X+k, Y+(S-k), s, N, M-1);
                Chess[X+k][Y+(S-k)] = '.';
                        Chess[X][Y] = 'L';
                    }
                    if(X+k<N && Y-(S-k)>=0 && Chess[X+k][Y-(S-k)] != 'P')
                    {
                        Chess[X+k][Y-(S-k)] = 'L';
                        Chess[X][Y] = '.';
                        sum1 += ways(DP, Chess, X+k, Y-(S-k), s, N, M-1);
                Chess[X+k][Y-(S-k)] = '.';
                        Chess[X][Y] = 'L';  
                    }
                    if(X-k>=0 && Y+(S-k) <N && Chess[X-k][Y+(S-k)] != 'P')
                    {
                        Chess[X-k][Y+(S-k)] = 'L';
                        Chess[X][Y] = '.';
                        sum1 += ways(DP, Chess, X-k, Y+(S-k), s, N, M-1);
                Chess[X-k][Y+(S-k)] = '.';
                        Chess[X][Y] = 'L';
                    }
                    if(X-k>=0 && Y-(S-k) >=0 && Chess[X-k][Y-(S-k)] != 'P')
                    {
                        Chess[X-k][Y-(S-k)] = 'L';
                        Chess[X][Y] = '.';
                        sum1 += ways(DP, Chess, X-k, Y-(S-k), s, N, M-1);
                            Chess[X-k][Y-(S-k)] = '.';
                        Chess[X][Y] = 'L';
                    }


                }
                else if(k==0 && (S-k)!=0)
                {
                    if(Y+(S-k)<N && Chess[X][Y+(S-k)] != 'P')
                    {
                        Chess[X][Y+(S-k)] = 'L';
                        Chess[X][Y] = '.';
                        sum1 += ways(DP, Chess, X, Y+(S-k), s, N, M-1);
                Chess[X][Y+(S-k)] = '.';
                        Chess[X][Y] = 'L';
                    }
                    if(Y-(S-k)>=0 && Chess[X][Y-(S-k)] != 'P')
                    {
                        Chess[X][Y-(S-k)] = 'L';
                        Chess[X][Y] = '.';
                        sum1 += ways(DP, Chess, X, Y-(S-k), s, N, M-1);
                Chess[X][Y-(S-k)] = '.';
                        Chess[X][Y] = 'L';
                    }


                }
                else if(k!=0 && (S-k)==0)
                {
                    if(X+k<N && Chess[X+k][Y] != 'P')
                    {
                        Chess[X+k][Y] = 'L';
                        Chess[X][Y] = '.';
                        sum1 += ways(DP, Chess, X+k, Y, s, N, M-1);
                Chess[X+k][Y] = '.';
                        Chess[X][Y] = 'L';
                    }
                    if(X-k>=0 && Chess[X-k][Y] != 'P')
                    {
                        Chess[X-k][Y] = 'L';
                        Chess[X][Y] = '.';
                        sum1 += ways(DP, Chess, X-k, Y, s, N, M-1);
                Chess[X-k][Y] = '.';
                        Chess[X][Y] = 'L';
                    }


                }
            }
    }
    //printf("X=%d Y=%d M=%d Val=%ld\n", X, Y, M, sum);
    DP[X][Y][M] = sum1;
        return sum1;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code. Instead, explain the problem (assume the link breaks tomorrow!) and your solution on a higher level.

Comment: Sorry dude, I'm new to stackexchage.

Comment: (Thank you for adding the ways function - but it would still help us immensely if you explained what you were trying to do in your code!)

Comment: DP[X][Y][M] means 'number of ways in which the S-leaper can move M steps'. For calculating the number of ways in which a S-leaper can move, I'm generating all (x,y) pairs such that x+y<=S. Generating all such pairs itself takes O(N^2).

Comment: That's a large piece of code, and this is not a programming site. This is definitely the right site to help you with the algorithm, but please meet us part of the way and explain your current solution with English word or ideally readable pseudocode.

Answer (score 5):

A big hint, since this is 'homework' of a sort: this (obviously?) isn't actually anything resembling a chess problem; instead, it's a *graph theory* problem in disguise.  Consider the graph with $n^2-P$ nodes, one for each cell of the board, and an edge between two nodes if they're a leaper-distance away; then the question is asking for the number of paths of length $M$ on this graph starting from a given point.  Now, think about a representation that uses an $n\times n$ array representing the number of paths (of a specific length) from the starting point to the given point.  Because the degree of the graph is small (there are roughly $2S^2$ individual moves from any given point), a single iteration (going from the length-$b$ paths to the length-$(b+1)$ paths) should take $O(n^2S^2)$ time and the full algorithm should run in time $O(n^2S^2M)$.

Note that the current algorithm as given by the code is *much* worse than this: each call to the `ways()` function is a *recursive* call, meaning that some values are being recomputed many, many times; its running time is, at first glance, roughly $O(S^{2M})$ (since a call to ways($M$) makes $S^2$ calls to ways($M-1$) and thus the running time $w(M) = S^2\cdot w(M-1)$).  Replacing that with an iterative approach where one loops $m$ from $1\ldots M$ and stores the number of paths of length $m$ to each cell, then uses the previous iteration's results to find all the paths of length $m+1$, should make a huge difference.

Comment: Correct me if I got this wrong. Use DFS on the graph till depth M. This won't be exactly DFS. We can revisit a node until we reach depth M. I can use DP and store (node, depth) which is number of paths of length **depth**. Need some clarification about these: a) Calculating all the node which are within leaper distance S will be O(N^2) in worst case. So doing that for all the nodes will be O(N^4) b) How is the degree of a node at most 8?

Comment: DFS isn't the most efficient way to do it in this case - while it's good at _finding_ paths, it's lousy at _counting_ paths.  Calculating the nodes that are within distance $S$ isn't $O(N^2)$, it's $O(S^2)$ - which, yes, could be $O(N^2)$ if $S$ is large, but should be tracked independently of $N$.

Comment: As for b), that's a straight-up error on my part; I'm used to the traditional definition of a leaper in fairy chess as a piece which moves specific distances (e.g., the knight is a (1,2) leaper) and missed that this was moving within a 'circle' of length $S$.  I've corrected my answer.

Comment: For calculating the number of paths of distance M, DP[node, M] = DP[node1, M-1] + DP[node2, M-1] +....+ DP[nodek, M-1] where **node1, node2, ... nodek** are adjacent to **node**. This is O(N^2.S^2.M) which in worst case is O(N^5). N <=200, so O(10^10). This is no different than my solution. I'm getting correct answer for small N using my code, but I get TLE for large N.

Comment: While it's accurate to call the algorithm $O(N^5)$, it's also misleading: $S$ is an _independent parameter_ and should be treated as such in the analysis.

Comment: Also, your algorithm is _not_ $O(N^2S^2M)$, because of the recursive calls; see my update.

Comment: >Note that the current algorithm as given by the code is much worse than this: each call to the ways() function is a recursive call, meaning that some values are being recomputed many, many times **---**  **I'm using Dynamic Programming to store the results** I know that recursive calls have overhead. Using a loop will be better, but still I'm not recomputing values.